# MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class: Why not just class names?

Tags: android

I have the the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I can't understand why do we put the keyword **this** with the current class and the keyword **class** with the name of the class we wish our intent to start.

What I know is:

**this** refers to the current instance of the class and **class** is a keyword we use to define new classes. Can somebody explain me what are we trying to say by using **this** and **class** with the name of classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#pubctors):

> public Intent (Context packageContext, Class cls) Added in API
>   level 1
>
> Create an intent for a specific component. All other fields (action,
>   data, type, class) are null, though they can be modified later with
>   explicit calls. This provides a convenient way to create an intent
>   that is intended to execute a hard-coded class name, rather than
>   relying on the system to find an appropriate class for you; see
>   setComponent(ComponentName) for more information on the repercussions
>   of this.
>
> Parameters
>
> packageContext    A Context of the application package implementing this class.
>
> cls   The component class that is to be used for the intent.

In simpler words: your constructor needs a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) and a [Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html). A Class refers to the Java class files that are created for a given Java source file, and it might be something currently not in use. Contexts is completely unrelated to Classes, as far as usage does, and when passed to a method, generally refer to something that has already been instanced.

Comment: So we use the keyword **class** to tell android that what we are passing is of type **class**. If you say 'yes', Why don't we do this with any other type? For example, I pass an integer value to a function, I don't tell andoird, "Hey, Andorid this was an int, don't misunderstand it." Why in the case with **class** only?

Comment: Because if you don't use the keyword class, the system will assume you're passing an [`Object`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html) of some sort named MainActivity (using your example), instead of its Java class file, and then the compiler will complain that there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

To make a new intent all you need to say is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**This** is defining the current class, whereas you wouldn't be able to use this for the next activity as it isn't the current class. You would use **class** for that.

Comment: I was using my code inside of an anonymous event click listener. Perhaps, therefore using the name of the class with the keyword **this** was a requirement. You can guide me!

Comment: Well, you use .this when you have another variable in the same scope of the same name. So this could be the issue with yours.

Answer (score 0):

this will also work fine, but when you are using dialog, then the keyword **this** doesn't refer to MainActivity. We use the keyword **this** to avoid those situations when we use MainActivity.this .If you are working in an Activity Class context, then using only **this** keyword works fine. Try it yourself and the reason for using the keyword **class**- I think the argument of Intent() method should be of class type, that;s why we pass class type argument to the function(constructor).

Comment: I edited your answer. Perhaps, this is what you were trying to say: anyhow I got the idea. Thanks :)